# what is this symbol mentioned in formula field?

Tags: community, formula-field

in an example i saw a symbol in formula fields. any one could you please say why its coming[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you hover on it, You see: **This formula references multiple objects** .So this is a sign for Cross-Object Formulas.

So it's **to differentiate normal formulas from cross object formulas**.